# Writing Stack methods while get() and elementAt() are overloaded?

Tags: java

I am new to this site and I've looked everywhere for an answer, and I can't find any solutions. Anyway, I'm writing a Stack method for a game and I have to implement all of the methods. However, my professor has overloaded `get(int index)` and `elementAt(int index)` in the Stack class. I'm trying to figure out how to finish the last methods `peek()`, `pop()` and `get()` without them using the overloaded methods. Thanks for any help, I'm new to this community and any help I can get is greatly appreciated!

```
class Goal
{
    private int MAX_SIZE = 5;
    private MyStack<String> goal;

    public Goal()
    {
    this(1);
    }

    public Goal(int numRandomSymbols)
    {
    goal = new MyStack<String>();
    for(int i=0; i< numRandomSymbols;i++){
        Symbol r = new Symbol();
        push(r.getSymbol());
    }
    }

    public boolean push(char input)
    {
    if (goal.size()!= MAX_SIZE){
            goal.push(String.valueOf(input));
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public int size()
    { 
        return goal.size();
}

    **public char get(int index)
    {  

        return ' ';
    }**


    **public char peek()
    { 
        return ' ';   
    }

    public char pop()
    { 
        return ' ';**
    }
    public boolean empty()
    {
        if(goal.size()>0){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
```

This is where all my trouble stems from:

```
import java.util.*;
public class MyStack<E> extends Stack<E>
{
    /* Overloading the Get method from the java
     * Stack class.  Because the stack in java extends
     * the vector class, some methods are inherited from
     * the vector class (such as get) but the undermine 
     * the role of a Stack                              */
    public E get(int index)
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("get() should not be available in a stack");
    }
    /* Overloading the elementAt method from the java
     * Stack class.  Because the stack in java extends
     * the vector class, some methods are inherited from
     * the vector class (such as get) but the undermine 
     * the role of a Stack                              */
    public E elementAt(int index)
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("elementAt() should not be available in a stack");
    }

}
```

Comment: **WE ARE NOT BLIND**

Comment: Are you sure you want/must implement `get(int)`? Seems odd.

Comment: Positive, his instructions were very vague. I've tried everything I could think of, but one way or another it throws an exception. Although most of the class had little difficulties, I don't completely understand what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Stack provides the methods `peek()` and `pop()`. If you really have to get the element from a specific position, you could simply use an `Iterator`. Though i highly doubt, that you'll need it, if your prof doesn't allow access by index.
Just for completeness:

```
public String get(int index){
    Iterator<String> iter = iterator();

    //let the iterator run through the stack as long as elements are available
    //and until you have reached the element before index
    for(int i = 0 ; i < index && iter.hasNext() ; i++)
         iter.next();

    //if another element is available for iter, return it
    //(it's the searched item) else return null
    return iter.hasNext() ? iter.next() : null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply! whenever I try and implement peek() for example:

goal.peek();

it throws the exception. This is what is extremely problematic for me, I realize this is probably a very simple answer and I am oblivious to something, but nevertheless I still can't figure it out. Thanks though!

Comment: For the exceptions: is the exception of type `UnsupportedOperationException`, or `EmptyStackException` (important difference!!!)?